# How to handle exception of "Page number does not exist" in PYTHON?

Tags: python

I have some lines of code that read a PDF file and extract the tables it contains in csv format, for that I use tabula-py, the code is as follows;

```
import tabula

file = "MyFile.pdf" 

tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "100", multiple_tables = True, stream=True)

tabula.convert_into(file, "MyFile.csv", pages="100")
```

When I enter a page number to the `pages` attribute of the `tabula.read_pdf` instruction but this page number does not exist in the PDF file, it throws me a type of error that I could not handle, the error would be the following;

```
Error from tabula-java:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Page number does not exist
    at technology.tabula.ObjectExtractor.extractPage(ObjectExtractor.java:19)
    at technology.tabula.PageIterator.next(PageIterator.java:29)
    at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractFile(CommandLineApp.java:166)
    at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractFileTables(CommandLineApp.java:129)
    at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractTables(CommandLineApp.java:111)
    at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.main(CommandLineApp.java:81)
```

What I am looking for is to be able to handle this exception, with a "try" or in some way that when entering a page number that does not exist in the PDF file it prints me with a "print" that the page was not found or does not exist.

If someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If I'm reading the [docs](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html) right, `read_pdf` creates a Pandas dataframe from a PDF file, while `convert_into` works directly from the file. In other words, your code as displayed creates a dataframe and then does nothing with it. You don't need that `tables = ...` line at all, if all you want to do is create the CSV output.

Answer (score 1):

1. According to the documentation, there are a number of exceptions you can try to catch in your code:

   > - FileNotFoundError – If downloaded remote file doesn’t exist.
   > - ValueError – If output_format is unknown format, or if downloaded remote file size is 0.
   > - tabula.errors.CSVParseError – If pandas CSV parsing failed.
   > - tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError – If java is not installed or found.
   > - subprocess.CalledProcessError – If tabula-java execution failed.

   [More info](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf)

---

2. Please check, maybe simple `pages="all"` will do what you need.

```py
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "all", multiple_tables = True, stream=True)
```

Comment: @JuanGomez If you want all the pages, `'all'` will do it; if you know you want a specific number of pages, presumably you already know how many pages are in your PDF; if it's some other case, mentioning why in your question might help clarify your intent.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I am making an interface in tkinter, and when the user adds a page number that is not in the PDF file, a message is printed that the page does not exist